# Demoiselle Signer e Assinador Digital do Serpro

Tags: demoiselle, demoiselle-certificate

Estou tentando usar o Demoiselle Signer para verificar a assinatura de um documento feito com o Assinador Digital de Documentos do Serpro (https://www5.serpro.gov.br/assinador-digital).

O código é bem simples:

```
    byte[] documento = getBytesFrom("assinatura/tema-228.pdf");
    byte[] assinatura = getBytesFrom("assinatura/tema-228.p7s");
    PKCS7Signer signer = PKCS7Factory.getInstance().factoryDefault();
    boolean ok = signer.check(documento, assinatura);
    System.out.println(ok);
```

Os arquivos utilizados no teste:

- Documento: https://expressodrive.serpro.gov.br/public.php?service=files&t=4730dbcb900d933e6df9b34e86693207&download
- Assinatura: https://expressodrive.serpro.gov.br/public.php?service=files&t=b54cdfd792b917c803d9556423b6da9c&download

Pom:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.component</groupId>
        <artifactId>demoiselle-certificate-signer</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

E o que aconteceu....

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.certificate.signer.pkcs7.impl.CAdESSigner.check(CAdESSigner.java:178)
    at br.gov.serpro.sislv.assinatura.DemoiselleSignerTest.shouldVerificarAssinatura(DemoiselleSignerTest.java:29)
```

Tentei usar a versão anterior do assinador:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.component</groupId>
        <artifactId>demoiselle-certificate-signer</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.9</version>
    </dependency>
```

Aí deu um outro erro:

```
br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.certificate.signer.SignerException: O Atributo signingCertificate não pode ser nulo.
    at br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.certificate.signer.pkcs7.bc.policies.ADRBCMS_2_1.validate(ADRBCMS_2_1.java:219)
    at br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.certificate.signer.pkcs7.bc.CAdESSigner.check(CAdESSigner.java:238)
    at br.gov.serpro.sislv.assinatura.DemoiselleSignerTest.shouldVerificarAssinatura(DemoiselleSignerTest.java:29)
```

O uso do Signer foi baseado na seguinte documentação:
http://demoiselle.sourceforge.net/docs/components/certificate/reference/2.0.0/html_single/#signer-funcionalidades

Dúvida: Como eu consigo verificar um documento assinado pelo Assinador do Serpro? Dá pra usar o Demoiseller Signer para isso?

Uma coisa ruim é que na página do Assinador ele não conta quais são os algoritmos utilizados =/
Será que esse assinador é basicamente o `Demoiselle Applet` com o `Demoiselle Signer`? Ou é outra coisa nada a ver?

Grato!
Leonardo Leite

PS: código do Demoiselle onde ocorre o `null pointer` na versão 2.0.0:

```
    AttributeTable unsignedAttributes = signer.getUnsignedAttributes();
    if (unsignedAttributes.size() == 0) { // null pointer aqui!
        logger.info("O pacote PKCS7 não contem atributos nao assinados.");
    }
```

Comment: Hoje foi publicada uma nova versão do Assinador do Serpro que agora é compatível com o verificador da ITI (https://verificador.iti.gov.br). Mas mesmo assim, o erro de verificação continuou o mesmo na versão 2.0.0 do Demoiselle Signer (não conferi na versão 1.0.9, mas pelo jeito também vai dar na mesma).

Answer (score 1):

Leonardo,

Para gerar uma assinatura você pode usar o demoiselle-certificate-signer: 
http://demoiselle.sourceforge.net/docs/components/certificate/reference/2.0.0/html_single/#d0e1950

Quanto a página do assinador não posso fornecer muitas informações, pois é uma aplicação do Serpro. Mas se usa o componente em sua versão mais atualizada (a partir da 1.0.8 ou 2.0.0) é gerada de acordo com as Políticas do ITI.
As políticas vigentes 2.0 e 2.1 usam SHA2 para criptografia.

Quanto ao NullPointer relatado na versão 2.0 é de fato um bug.
Relatei o bug em https://demoiselle.atlassian.net/browse/CER-6 e deve sair uma correção na próxima versão.

Quando ao erro relatado na versão 1, peço que verifique novamente já que houve uma nova versão do assinador.

Comment: Esses dias saiu uma nova versão do Assinador e o problema já foi corrigido!